# In the non-Newtonian flow, what's the difference between Carreau–Bird model and FENE-P model

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

Can [FENE-P model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FENE-P) describe the shear-thinning or shear-thickening flow?

Comment: C'mon, give a bit more information here! What does FENE-P mean? What's a "shear-thickening flow"? Making your question accesible and showing your research increases the chance of upvotes and makes answerers more likely to invest time into an answer!

Comment: I've added a link to FENE-P's wikipedia page; if you feel it insufficient in detail, please modify the link to a source more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, then I think I ran into a wrong place. These are questions too specific. If you are expert in non-Newtonian flow, it's would be an easy question to answer. Shear-thickening flow means the viscosity increases with the shear.

Comment: @jengmge: I don't believe this is the "wrong place" for such a question. The issue is that, to non-experts (more appropriately, non-practitioners), the question does not appear to contain enough information to be accessible to the future visitors to the site; hence ACuriousMind's comment.

Answer (score 0):

FENE models are a class of model to describe a viscoelastic fluid flow, . Although these flows exhibit shear-dependent flow rates, they are not equivalent to shear-thickening or shear-thinning flows.